# It’s working but I don’t understand why. It's about arguments to callbacks

Tags: python, tkinter

It’s working but I don’t understand why. I was able to play around until I found something that works and it depends upon hidden “default” arguments in callbacks, but I thought the “event” was the only hidden argument. I wanted to pass the class “self” also. I want an event in a tkinter class to call an external function (external to the class) and I want to pass the event and the class (“self”) as arguments. To do this I call internal functions which then call the external functions.
The confusing point is that I must do it differently for a call from a bind and a call from a button command. It works and does what I want but I also want to understand what is happening. I also would like to know if there is a better way. The following code is all within the class.

```
self.B1 = Button(self.frame_controls, text = "Go", command=lambda: self.process_go_internal(self))
self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.process_configure_internal)

   def process_go_internal(event, rt):
        process_go_external(rt, event)

    def process_configure_internal(self, event):
        process_configure(self, event)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: That was a handful to read... Did you go through a debugger step by step?

Comment: You don't need to explicitly pass `self` to `self.process_go_internal()` as `self` is implicitly passed as the first argument.  And you should define `process_go_internal()` like `def process_go_internal(self)`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, it's difficult to see what you are doing when you are not supplying working code. However I'll provide an example of how you could do what I think you are trying to do:

The `bind()` function generates an event but the `Button()` does not, so you will have to treat them accordingly. I have them call different methods within the class.

In the `button_press()` method I supply a default value for event as there is no event passed by the Button.

As for passing a reference to the instance you can just pass it as you would any name.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def external_function(instance, event):
    print('external_function instance:', instance)
    print('external_functionevent:', event)
    print()
    instance.do_it()    # Try to call the Cheese instance

class Cheese():
    def __init__(self):
        root.bind('<Configure>', self.configure)
        B1 = Button(root, text='Go', command=self.button_press)
        B1.pack(padx=100, pady=20)

    def configure(self, event):
        print('<Configure>')
        external_function(self, event)  # Passing instance ref and event

    def button_press(self, event=None):
        print('Button press')
        print()
        external_function(self, event)  # Passing instance ref and event

    def do_it(self):
        print("I'm doing it!")
        print()

c = Cheese()

root.mainloop()
```

Was this helpful?